# Can someone please explain this?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have two tables,

- `reorder_table(item_id number,stock_level number) and`
- `stock(item_id number,item_desc varchar2(20),stock_level number)`

[image]

according to this data `PEN` and `PENCIL` should need a reordering as their stock level is below reorder stock value.

I have a log table `sql_errors` that logs the items that need re ordering.  here is my code

```
DECLARE
  out_of_stock EXCEPTION;
  v_item       VARCHAR2(20);
  CURSOR inv_cur
  IS
    SELECT a.item_id,
      b.item_desc,
      a.stock_level reorder_level,
      b.stock_level stock_level
    FROM reorder_level a,
      stock b
    WHERE a.item_id=b.item_id ;
BEGIN
  BEGIN -- sub block
    FOR c IN inv_cur
    LOOP
      IF c.reorder_level > c.stock_level THEN
        v_item :=c.item_desc;
        raise out_of_stock;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN out_of_stock THEN
    INSERT INTO sql_errors VALUES
      ('Item '||v_item|| ' Is out of Stock');
  END; -- sub block ends
END;
```

I have written the inner block so that the execution continues even after exception is raised and logs all the items that need re ordering.  but in the log table only the item `PENCIL` is getting logged. NOT PEN.

why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that a `RAISE` will send the control the `EXCEPTION` block it is in. And After Execution, the block is completed. In your case, the `LOOP` is written in the sub block itself, so on `Exception` the control moved away from the sub-block after the first exception. 
I have moved your sub-block for the one inside the `LOOP` as below.

```
DECLARE
  out_of_stock EXCEPTION;
  v_item       VARCHAR2(20);
  CURSOR inv_cur
  IS
    SELECT a.item_id,
      b.item_desc,
      a.stock_level reorder_level,
      b.stock_level stock_level
    FROM reorder_level a,
      stock b
    WHERE a.item_id=b.item_id ;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN inv_cur
  LOOP
    BEGIN -- sub block
       IF c.reorder_level > c.stock_level THEN
         v_item :=c.item_desc;
         raise out_of_stock;  /* goes to the exception block */
       END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN out_of_stock THEN
      INSERT INTO sql_errors VALUES
        ('Item '||v_item|| ' Is out of Stock');
    END; -- sub block ends
    /* Loop Continues! */
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using an exception instead of just doing the insert when you you detect that an item is out of stock?

```
if c.reorder_level > c.stock_level then

     v_item :=c.item_desc;

     insert into sql_errors 
     values ('Item '||v_item|| ' Is out of Stock');

end if;
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to understand how to continue execution even when an exception is raised.  in this case I was trying to log the item and continue execution when an exception is raised.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00701, it looks like control cannot return to point that raised the exception:

After an exception handler runs, control transfers to the next statement of the enclosing block. If there is no enclosing block, then:

If the exception handler is in a subprogram, then control returns to the invoker, at the statement after the invocation.

If the exception handler is in an anonymous block, then control transfers to the host environment (for example, SQL*Plus)

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into sql_errors 
    select 'Item '||b.item_desc|| ' Is out of Stock'
    from reorder_level a, stock b
    where a.item_id = b.item_id and a.stock_level > b.stock_level
```